# Multiple statements on a single variable in a pipeline

Tags: powershell

I'm sure somehow somewhere this has been answered before but despite driving myself crazy I can't seem to find it.Newer to Powershell and coding in general, any critiques welcome.

I want to look at a series of logs and output the name of the log followed by the number of times a string was found or the number of lines that contain a certain string.  Either should work.

What I have right now is the following

```
$logsToCheck = "F:\errlog1.txt",
                "F:\errlog2.txt"
$errMatches = foreach($log in $logsToCheck)
     {Write-Host $log; Select-String -Path $log -Pattern "ERRORBAD"}
$errMatches
```

My goal is something like an output of just the name of the log and the number of errors such as:

```
F:\errlog1.txt
12
F:\errlog2.txt
7
```

I thought about just making variables for each log in the loop I have and printing the path name and then something like

```
$countErrLog1 = Select-String -Path F:\errlog1.txt -Pattern "ERRORBAD"
$countErrLog1.Matches.Count
```

But that seems rather redundant.

So what I end up looking for is how to pass multiple statements to a single variable in the pipeline before moving on to the next variable in the pipe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are on? You can get it with `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy with `Select-String` and `Group-Object`.

```
$logsToCheck = "F:\errlog1.txt",
                "F:\errlog2.txt"
Select-String -Path $logsToCheck -Pattern 'ERRORBAD' | 
    Group Path | 
    Select Count,Name
```

That will output something like:

```
Count Name
----- ----
   12 F:\errlog1.txt
    7 F:\errlog2.txt
```

Comment: Didn't even know about this command.  Gives me the output I want and works perfectly but you just used "Group" and not "Group-Object".  They both give me the same output but don't seem to be the same or are they?  Just making sure I understand.

Comment: They're the same command. `Group` is just a shorter alias for `Group-Object`

Answer (score 0):

You are actually really close already.  Something to consider is that Count returns NOTHING if it's zero, so you need to use `@()` to force PowerShell to give you an array.

Here is the code I used:

```
$logsToCheck = "test.txt","test2.txt"
foreach($log in $logsToCheck)
{
    $matchInfo = @(Select-String -Path $log -Pattern "ERROR")

    Write-Host $log $matchInfo.Count
}
```

test.txt:

```
ERROR
GOOD
GOOD
ERROR
ERROR
```

text2.txt

```
GOOD
GOOD
GOOD
GOOD
GOOD
```

My results:

```
test.txt 3
test2.txt 0
```

Comment: This works great too and while it doesn't format it like the other answer I still plan on using this in the future.  Gave me a much better insight into how the code is read.